return from lambda inside another lambda kotlin
a have a function:
private fun getInvoices() = viewModelScope.launch {
        getPaidInvoices(
            onSuccess = {

            },
            onFailure = {
                // i need to exit from getInvoices function here
            }
        )
        
        // another api function
    }

This is my code for executing an api request in getPaidInvoices function, below is another api function. I need to make it so that if in the first function (getPaidInvoices) I get into the onFailure block, then exit the getInvoices function so that the next request is no longer executed, how can this be done?

Lambdas can only have non-local returns if they are arguments to inline functions.   So, your definition of the getPaidInvoices() function must be marked inline for this to be possible.
Then, inside your onFailure lambda, you can use return@launch to return from your launched coroutine early. This is what is called a non-local return. You are using @launch to specify which function you want to return from. Without the qualifier you would be returning from the local function, in this case the immediately surrounding lambda.
Note this is not the same as returning from getInvoices() since the code in your coroutine is launched and then getInvoices() immediately returns with the Job representing your long running work of the coroutine. I’m just assuming returning from the coroutine earlier is what you actually are asking how to do.
